# Get integer from Textbox

Tags: c#, textbox, integer

I am very new to C# and this question might sound very stupid. I wonder how I'm going get the integer(user's input) from the `textBox1` and use it in if else statement?

Please give some examples

Comment: hello Tanya, it would be great if you could include the code you have written so far - the answers at the moment are rather general so that would make it possible to improve them a great deal.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to parse the value of `textbox.Text` which is a string to `int` value. You may use [int.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx), or [`int.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse.aspx) or [`Convert.ToInt32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b.aspx).

`TextBox.Text` property is of `string` type. You may look at the following sample code.

**int.TryParse**

This will return true if the parsing is successful and false if it fails.

```
int value;

if(int.TryParse(textBox1.Text,out value))
{
//parsing successful 
} 
else
{
//parsing failed. 
}
```

**Convert.ToInt32**

This may throw an exception if the parsing is unsuccessful.

```
int value = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
```

**int.Parse**

```
int value = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
```

Later you can use `value` in your if statement like.

```
if(value > 0)
{
}
else
{
}
```

Comment: After doing some searches i did find what you're trying to say but it every time it says "input string was not in a correct format" :(

Comment: @TanyaLertwichaiworawit, what is inside your textBox.Text property ?

Answer (score 3):

Try with this:

```
int i = int.Parse(textbox1.Text);
```

Comment: It saids "inputn string was not in correct format" Please help, thanks

Comment: Sorry for the late response, try to use the Int32.TryParse() method instead. Or put the code into a try-catch block like in the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
    int value = 0;
    if (Int32.TryParse(textbox.Text, out value))
    {
       if (value == 1)
       {
          ... //Do something
       }
       else if (value == 2)
       {
          ... //Do something else
       }
       else
       {
          ... //Do something different again
       }
   }
   else
   {
       ... //Incorrect format...
   }
```

Comment: This will produce an exception when a user enters a letter

Comment: I changed it to the Int32.TryParse-Method. It returns true if it was able to parse the string (textbox.Text) to a integer. the value is written as an out-reference. So it is set in the TryParseMethod as well...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
string value = myTextBox.Text;
int myNumber = 0;

if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
{
    int.TryParse(value, out myNumber);
    if(myNumber > 0)
    {
         // do stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

```
        try 
        {
            int myNumber = Int32.Parse(myTextBox.Text);
        }
        catch (FormatException ex)
        {
           //failed, not a valid number in string
            throw;
        }
```

or

```
        int myNumber = 0;
        if (Int32.TryParse(myTextBox.Text, out myNumber))
        { 
            //success do something with myNumber
        }
```