# Taking user input and multiplying it by a number

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var x = textBox1.Text;
    var y = 1000000;
    var answer = x * y;
}
```

This is my current code. I want to take the user input from `textBox1` and multiply it by 1000000 because it needs to convert the user input. But This code doesn't because `x` technically isn't a numerical value. How would I get this functioning?

Comment: `textbox1.;` is a syntax error. Did you mean `textbox1.Text;`?

Comment: You're looking for this: [How can I convert String to Int?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019793/how-can-i-convert-string-to-int)

Comment: You might want to have a look at this quistion/answer:

[Get integer from textbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11931770/get-integer-from-textbox)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Int32.Parse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse(v=vs.110).aspx) if you're sure user input is a number or [`int.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) if you need to validate it.

I'm assuming integer inputs only what could be wrong though. Same applies for other numeric types. (they all have `Parse` and `TryParse`)

**Using `Int32.Parse`**

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var x = Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text); // you're sure text is numeric
     var y = 1000000;
     var answer = x * y;
}
```

**Using `Int32.TryParse`**

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     int x = 0;
     if (Int32.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out x)) // you're NOT sure if text is numeric
     {
          var y = 1000000;
          var answer = x * y;
     }
     else 
     {
          // let the user know that numeric values are required
     }
}
```

Comment: want to show usage of `TryParse`?

Comment: This worked for me, I have no errors, but now I want it to display to displayLabel2. When I do    displayLabel2.Text = answer;   it says it cant convert int to string.

Comment: @Justin Dosaj: do `displayLabel2.Text = answer.ToString()`

Comment: You're the best <3 thanky ou

Answer (score 3):

This is getting text, not a number:

```
var x = textBox1.Text;
```

Since C# is statically typed, you need to explicitly turn it into a number.  For this you can use something like `int.TryParse()`.  For example:

```
var xText = textBox1.Text;
var x = 0;
if (!int.TryParse(xText, out x))
{
    // display an error to the user
    return;
}
var y = 1000000;
var answer = x * y;
```

That way you're testing if the text input *can* be parsed as a number and, if it can't, displaying a message to the user.  Rather than assuming the input and getting an unhandled exception.

There are also `TryParse()` methods for other numeric types, in case you want to use something like a `double` or a `float` for other calculations.

Answer (score -4):

This will get you your numerical values

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            float x = Float.Parse(textBox1.text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            float y = 1000000;
            float answer = x * y;
        }
```

Comment: syntax error, don't just copy/paste...

Comment: your syntax on your first statement isn't valid.  `float x = textBox1.text` isn't a valid argument.

Comment: @NathanA read it again

Comment: @Andrew I am, still not valid...

Comment: `float x = Float.Parse(float x = textBox1.text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` `Float.Parse()` returns a `float`

Comment: Try running that through a compiler, and then come back...

Comment: okay the params i overlooked