# c# TextBox how to get the last letter of a string?

Tags: c#, string, textbox

```
 private void inputBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        stringScan();
        var regex1 = new Regex(@"[^+^\-^\b^\r\n]");
        var regex2 = new Regex(@"[^0-9^+^\-^/^*^#^\b^\r\n]");

        if (ListBox.Items.Count == 0 && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(inputBox.Text))
        {
            if (regex1.IsMatch(e.KeyChar.ToString()))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                toolTip1.Show("Plus or minus first then followed by numbers.", inputBox, 1500);

            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (regex2.IsMatch(e.KeyChar.ToString()))
            {
               e.Handled = true;  
            }
        }

    }

    public void stringScan()
    {
        char last_char = inputBox.ToString()[inputBox.ToString().Length - 1];
        Console.WriteLine(last_char);
    }
```

How can i get the last letter/number of a string?. Its really hard to explain so I'll show some screenshots.

[image: This is the input]

[image: and this is the output]

the output should show "0"  not "1".
It always show the "previews last" and not the latest one that i typed in the textbox.

Comment: try `(?s).$` ..............

Comment: in a single line textbox there is no line feed at the end

Comment: Doesn't `myString[myString.Length-1]` return the last character?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember, when the event `inputBox_KeyPress` is raised, the typed key isn't added yet. Also, don't use regex for this. It will be overcomplicated.

Try the `TextChanged` event.

Answer (score 0):

Text box key change will be executed every time u change the content of the text box

So for every value u enter u will be calling the string scan

This can be limited if u know what length the text is going to be

Answer (score 0):

What about you try this:

```
public void stringScan()
{

    String last_char = inputBox.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(last_char[last_char.Length-1]);
}
```

Comment: How it makes difference?

Comment: Since i couldn't determine an underlying problem, my first thought is that he's calling the wrong part of the text in the inputbox.
His question is literally: "How can i get the last letter/number of a string?"
This is how if i'm not mistaken..

Answer (score 0):

If you want last typed char I suggest:

```
private void inputBox_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
            Console.WriteLine(e.Text);
}
```

If you want last char in textbox I suggest  TextChanged event as already told by Jeroen van Langen:

```
private void inputBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string inputString = ((TextBox)sender).Text;
    char lastChar = inputString.Last();
    Console.WriteLine(lastChar);
}
```

Hope code samples help you

Edit:
Now I get that you probably want to get integer from textbox, if that's the matter, [Get integer from Textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11931770/get-integer-from-textbox) could help you, code sample:

```
 private void inputBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        string inputString = ((TextBox)sender).Text;

        int valueFromTextBox;
        if (int.TryParse(inputString, out valueFromTextBox))
        {
            //parsing successful 
        }
        else
        {
            //parsing failed. 
        }
    }
```